# Deleting admin local group member script doesnt work

Tags: powershell

I created the below script to delete the Specified Members from Administrators Group but it crashes when it can't find the member. Specificaly it shows my code and in the end adds
: An unspecifed error occured
At line:21 char:5
"An unspecifed error occured" | Write-Error
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException"

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

#User to search for
$MEMBERS = @("Test1","Test5","Test2","Test76","Test3")
foreach ($MEMBER in $MEMBERS) {

#Declare LocalUser Object
$ObjLocalGroupMember = $null

try {
    Write-Verbose "Searching for $($MEMBER) in LocalGroup DataBase"
    $ObjLocalGroupMember = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $MEMBER
    Write-Verbose "User $($MEMBER) was found"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberNotFoundException] {
    "User $($MEMBER) was not found" | Write-Error
}
catch  {
    "An unspecifed error occured" | Write-Error
    Exit
}

if ($ObjLocalGroupMember) {
    Write-Verbose "Deleting User $($MEMBER)" 
    
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$op = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"| Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $MEMBER}
if ($op)
 {
  Remove-LocalGroupMember ($op) | Out-Null
  }
 }
}
```

I am still very new in this so the solution could be very simple but your help will be very much apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is your use of [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error?view=powershell-7.2) in combination with [`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference), since the preference is **Stop**, the *non-terminating error* generated by `Write-Error` will be treated as a **terminating error**, hence the script stops at first occurrence of an error.

The other main issue is your use of [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2#exit) instead of [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2#continue) in your `catch` block, but also to explain why it's reaching that `catch` statement, you're trying to catch the error type **`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberNotFoundException`** however, when `Get-LocalGroupMember` **can't find a member**, the exception type is **`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PrincipalNotFoundException`**:

```
try {
    Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member doesnotexist
}
catch {
    $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
}

# Results in: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PrincipalNotFoundException`
```

As for your code, you could simplify it a bit, there are some not needed redundancies:

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

#User to search for
$members = "Test1", "Test5", "Test2", "Test76", "Test3"
foreach($member in $members) {
    try {
        Write-Verbose "Searching for $member in LocalGroup DataBase"
        $ObjLocalGroupMember = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member $member
        Write-Verbose "User $member was found"
        Write-Verbose "Deleting User $member" 
        Remove-LocalGroupMember $ObjLocalGroupMember
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PrincipalNotFoundException] {
        Write-Warning "User $member was not found"
        continue # Go to next user
    }
    catch  {
        # Adding `$_` so at least you know what happened
        Write-Warning "An unspecifed error occured: $_"
        continue
    }

    # Unclear what is this doing here, never being used and
    # should also be outside the loop in any case:
    # $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
}
```

Comment: That  looks neater and for sure simpler. As I said I am still a rookie so i google and implement what i  think that will work and seems closer to my situation hence the previous mess. Now the problem with your code is that when I run it it asks to supply values for the following paramaters Member. Ill try to solve it though. Nevertheless thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: @teodallas happy to help, don't need to worry about being rookie we all have been at some point. My intent with the code is mainly to help you learn something new. Regarding the issue asking to provide a member, the only possible reason for that is that the `$members` variable containing the users to remove hasn't been defined?

Comment: I tried also to define it even though i dont think it was nessesary but still nothing...

Comment: @teodallas you can edit your question and paste your current code as you have it now and I can inspect it to see if there is something wrong (make sure to copy paste it literally)

Comment: I actualy used the code you sent me with and without tweaks. But what worked for me up to a point was adding the -member parameter to Remove-LocalGroupMember

Comment: Thats the new error: WARNING: An unspecifed error occured: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named pa
rameters